# Possible EventHandler for when a user clicks out of a textfield?

Tags: java, javafx

So, when using the code:

```
textField.setOnAction();
```

It only functions with the Enter key, but I'm just wondering if there's some sort of EventHandler for a TextField and TextArea that can save the text within its field to an object's instance variable when a user clicks away or to another TextField? For example:

```
textField.setOnMouse(e -> 
{
object.setText(textField.)
});
```

This code would save the information within it's field, once the user clicks away from the TextField.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can respond to it losing focus:

```
textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
    if (! isNowFocused) {
        // do whatever you need
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the required commit (aka: save user input to a model/data object) semantics are

- commit-on-action: that's typically triggered by ENTER (available on TextField, but not on TextArea)
- commit-on-focusLost: that's triggered when focus is transfered from an input control to somewhere else, can happen by mouse or tab, f.i.

and that they are not:

- commit-on-change: that is update the data whenever the input control's textProperty is changed

The suggested [approach by James](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49311808/203657) is to *also* register a focusListener on the control that does the same job as the action handler:

```
// in actionHandler
textField.setOnAction(e -> myData.setText(textField.getText()));
// in listener when receiving a focusLost
textField.focusedProperty().addListener((... ) -> myData.setText(textField.getText()))
```

Perfectly valid!

Just pointing to an alternative: FX has support to achieve both-in-one, and that's a TextFormatter. It guarantees to update its value on both commit-on-action and commit-on-focusLost, but not on typing. So we can bind the data property (bidirectionally, if needed) to the formatter's value and naturally have the required commit semantic.

A snippet that demonstrates its usage (the Labels are just stand-ins for the data):

```
private Parent createTextContent() {
    TextFormatter<String> fieldFormatter = new TextFormatter<>(
            TextFormatter.IDENTITY_STRING_CONVERTER, "textField ...");
    TextField field = new TextField();
    field.setTextFormatter(fieldFormatter);
    Label fieldValue = new Label();
    fieldValue.textProperty().bind(fieldFormatter.valueProperty());
    TextFormatter<String> areaFormatter = new TextFormatter<>(
            TextFormatter.IDENTITY_STRING_CONVERTER, "textArea ...");
    TextArea area = new TextArea();
    area.setTextFormatter(areaFormatter);
    Label areaValue =  new Label();
    areaValue.textProperty().bind(areaFormatter.valueProperty());

    HBox fields = new HBox(100, field, fieldValue);
    BorderPane content = new BorderPane(area);
    content.setTop(fields);
    content.setBottom(areaValue);
    return content;
}
```